# How can I hold an object in buffer?

Tags: c#

When I tried this code on server(after local) it is failed because of filepath changes on it. How can I hold xmldoc object on buffer or somewhere else before writing? If I can write to buffer, no need to filepath and it will be independent from a path. Or anyone suggest a different way?

```
const string fileName = "123.xml";
string filePath = Server.MapPath("123.xml");
var xmlDoc = new StreamWriter(filePath);
dataSet.WriteXml(xmlDoc);
xmlDoc.Close();
```

Comment: What do you meant by *it is failed because of filepath changes on it*?

Comment: You could use a `MemoryStream`

Comment: Are you saying that say the physical file system was changed in between instancing the stream and closing it?

Comment: this code is part of a website that published on server. When someone tried to reach this page from his/her local and create xml then save to local, it is giving an error about filepath. It can not be found

Answer (score 1):

Here's a reference on using a `MemoryStream` in conjunction with Xml Documents:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tolong/archive/2007/11/15/read-write-xml-in-memory-stream.aspx

Answer (score 1):

You could use [this constructor : StreamWriter Constructor (Stream)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wtbhzte9.aspx) overload and use a [MemoryStream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.memorystream.aspx)

You can try something like

```
using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
{
    var sw = new StreamWriter(stream);
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if this is what you're looking for but I use memory mapped files to manage temp data. [Here](http://gunnarpeipman.com/2009/06/net-framework-4-0-using-memory-mapped-files/) is a great article, short and with working examples.